# Error log on Laravel 5 with the URL where error occurred

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, logging, error-logging, error-log

I want to append to each error log, the URL of the page the user requested before the error occurred. The logs already give me where the error occurs, but it's valuable for me know the URL.

I saw there is a Handler.php file but how can I append the URL there?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's quite simple, on your **app/Exceptions/Handler.php** on top the of it add this two imports:

```
use Request;
use Log;
```

Then on your report method add this:

```
public function report(Exception $e) {
    Log::info($e->getMessage(), [
        'url' => Request::url(),
        'input' => Request::all()
    ]);
    return parent::report($e);
}
```

Now whenever you get an exception the **current url** is logged and the request parameters either **GET** or **POST** will also be logged:

```
[2016-02-10 19:25:13] local.INFO: Error Processing Request {"url":"http://localhost:8002/list","input":{"name":"fabio","surname":"antunes"}}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks guys, very usefull.

Comment: I found out the hard way: be sure to unset `password` and `password_confirmation` from the `Request::all()` array before writing that to logs. Major security risk!

Comment: I think its better not to include the inputs anyway, with url + line of error it's enough to start debugging

Comment: It should be: 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

Comment: @MartijnHiemstra these are aliased normally in config/app.php

Answer (score 21):

Even better way of doing this:

In **App\Exceptions\Handler** extend Laravel's base **context()** function:

```
use Throwable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;


/**
 * Get the default context variables for logging.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function context()
{
    try {
        return array_filter([
            'url' => Request::fullUrl(),
            'input' => Request::except(['password', 'password_confirmation']),
            'userId' => Auth::id(),
            'email' => Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->email : null,
        ]);
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: Not working in Laravel 5.2. (I know its old version but stuck on this due to some business reasons)

Comment: Which page do I add this code and how should I extend Laravel's  context and connect it with my app/Exceptions/Handler

Comment: @EmmanuelDavid you add it to the "App\Exceptions\Handler.php", it all says in the description

Answer (score 4):

You can extend **context()** method in **App\Exceptions\Handler**. In this implementation, you keep original method and just expand the data array.

```
protected function context()
{
    try {
        $context = array_filter([
            'url' => Request::url()
        ]);
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        $context = [];
    }

    return array_merge($context, parent::context());
}
```